# Formula to find&replace part of a string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

> Column A contains the string you want to edit.
> Column C contains a string to find some word in the string in column A.
> Column D contains the string that replaces that string.
> Results are returned in column F.

This is the result I want.

| a | b | c | d | e | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  | result |
| its test. apple |  | apple | A |  | its test. A |
| its test. banana |  | banana | B |  | its test. B |
| apple & banana |  | ... | ... |  | A & B |
| banana & banana |  |  |  |  | B & B |
| its test. apple |  |  |  |  | its test. A |
| its test. banana |  |  |  |  | its test. B |

I used this formula.
`=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, C2:D, 2,TRUE))`

and i got this wrong.

| a | b | c | d | e | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  | result |
| its test. apple |  | apple | A |  | B |
| its test. banana |  | banana | B |  | B |
| apple & banana |  | ... | ... |  | A |
| banana & banana |  |  |  |  | B |
| its test. apple |  |  |  |  | B |
| its test. banana |  |  |  |  | B |

I want to return only some of the strings have changed. If there are several texts to change in one string, I want to change them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=REDUCE(A:A,C:C,LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c="",a, INDEX (REGEXREPLACE(a,c,OFFSET(c,0,1))))))
```

It's a basic REGEXREPLACE, but with REDUCE lets you scan the different words to be replaced

[image]

With Substitute:

```
=REDUCE(A:A,C:C,LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c="",a, INDEX (SUBSTITUTE(a,c,OFFSET(c,0,1))))))
```

Comment: Do special characters affect formulas? For example, if the text in column A is 'apple' and the value in column C is 'apple?!?', the returned value will be banana. Is it because the formula uses regular expressions?

Comment: Try with Substitute, I've posted the formula